# SQL LIMIT query not woking

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
  include 'DBConnect.php';
  $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
  $query = "SELECT * FROM telejoke.jokes LIMIT 2";
  $data = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed' . mysql_error());
  $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ); 
  mysql_close($conn);
  echo json_encode($info);   
?>
```

For instance, if I put LIMIT 2, I want only the first 2 rows from the table to be gathered, encoded into a JSON Array and echoed. Regardless of this LIMIT number, `echo json_encode($info);` it prints out the whole table.

Trying `echo json_encode($data);` results in null output.

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
$info = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
  $info[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($info);
```

Comment: yea this worked. Just realized I wasn't grabbing all the data. It wasn't printing the whole table, just the first entry.

Answer (score 0):

trying doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM telejoke.jokes LIMIT 0,2
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM jokes LIMIT 0,2
```